# react.js test if node server running

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm learning React.js. My React.js app and Node Server use:

```
Server: MongoDb, Mongoose, Express, Cors, Axios.
React.js app: BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link.
```

When my React.js app starts, I want to test if the Node Server is running before making any database requests.

How can I best do that? (use ping somehow?)

Comment: Make a request to the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not really a way to tell if a server is up without attempting to communicate with that server. But it's relatively simple to set up an endpoint on your server that will tell you whether it's running. Just set up a simple route in express that unconditionally sends a successful status code. If you get a response from that, you know at least that Express is running:

```
app.get('/status', (req, res, next) => res.sendStatus(200));
```